# How to test wine via live usb stick?

Tags: wine, live-usb

I want to test wine with a current Ubuntu live image.

I managed to install `ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso` on a USB stick. The resulting USB stick boots alright.

Unfortunately, the live image does not include wine.

I noticed that the root file system is an overlay one - the overlay is stored in RAM.

The problem is that the test system does not have that much RAM - i.e. modifying `/etc/apt/sources.lst` and `apt-get install wine` works on the live system - but a few packages eat all the available RAM and the system halts.

Plus - I also need some space for installing the windows application (to test it).

Is it possible to use a spare partition on the USB stick for the root-overlay?

Then I would have enough space for the wine packages and the windows application - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `usb-creator-kde` and a USB stick which is 2 GB or larger. The tool presents options to use some space for persistent storage on the USB stick.

In case the stick is smaller than 2 GB, the options are not available.

The persistent storage is configured as loopback-filesystem-file on the stick (4 GB max). This file is then use as overlay on the live system (instead of RAM).

This works quite well - `apt-get install` and `wine` work as expected and everything is written to the stick.

On my Ubuntu 11.04 system, the usb-creator was a bit picky. With a 16 GB stick it failed to write the boot sector. `usb-creator-gtk` did not report the problem - `udb-creator-kde` did report it. With another stick `sudo usb-creator-kde` started the GUI etc. - but the resulting stick did not boot. With `usb-creator-kde` inside a `sudo su -` the installation on the same stick worked and the live system booted.

I looked into the `initrd.lv` of the resulting USB stick and noticed in `scripts/casper` that the live system checks if `persistent` is given as boot parameter and if it can find a ext2 filesystem labeled `casper-rw` - if so it uses that as overlay.

This mechanism is also [documented at the Ubuntu-wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent). But I didn't manage to create a second partition on the stick that is recognized by the live system. I failed to create first the partition and instruct usb-creator to just use the first one. I also failed to let usb-creator create the live system and then use `gparted` to shrink it and create a second partition (as described at the Wiki) - the resulting stick would not boot anymore.

Comment: `usb-creator-gtk` can do the same.

Comment: @Oxwivi, sure, `usb-creator-gtk` should be functional equivalent to `usb-creator-kde` - but on my system `usb-creator-gtk` did not display an important error message (see also the answer) - `usb-creator-kde` did.